# Where should parameters be put when CloudFormation is used with CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

When I use CodePipeline to deploy my CloudFormation stack, it needs parameters set all the time ... so far, I hope I am correct?

> Parameters: [xxx, yyy, ...] must have values (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 43e9ede4-a352-11e8-bfe2-15cc69824d50)

My current setup is something like:

- 1 Stack for CI/CD (CodePipeline, CodeBuild, and deploy infra using CloudFormation)
- 1 Stack for "actual" infra: DB, ECS Cluster etc

I need to define my parameters both in CI and actual stack. This is because CI stack will need to pass these parameters into the actual stack ... this seems wrong.

Ideally I want my CI stack to only know about whats needed for CI/CD not the environment variables the actual stack requires?

---

**UPDATE: A possible solution?**

I tried to have 1 additional stack: a "config" stack that will store everything in EC2 parameter store, but it seems like CloudFormation cannot define Secrets

> AWS CloudFormation doesn't support the SecureString parameter type. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html)

So maybe I will have my actual infra stack save all parameters into EC2 parameter store via CodeBuild then my CI stack will read from this. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Actually few day ago AWS announced that SecureString parameters now are supported for AWS CloudFormation:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/aws-cloudformation-introduces-dynamic-references-to-support-aws-/

Although I tried tested it yesterday and today — it just doesn't seems to work, CloudFormation refuses all updates with CFN parameters of type `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<SecureString>`. It just throws such exception: `ValidationError: Template format error: Unrecognized parameter type: SecureString`

Comment: Can you please clarify your idea how do you want to use a "config" stack exactly?
And what is the actual problem with your CI/CD stack knows about envs of your production stack? 
And did you considered use only one stack where you will describe all resources: both CI/CD such a Pipeline, CodeBuild etc and your prod resources, such as ECS cluster? You can configure your Pipeline to deploy immediately to ECS services with CodeDeploy.

Comment: Oh, I've found that I was wrong how to use SecureString parameters. You could not use it as simple parameter values, although you are able to have a dynamic reference on such parameters from SSM.
But you permitted to use it for very limited set of resource attributes, learn the details in the end of the doc:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

Comment: @SergeyCherepanov, I guess I could, but I am thinking of splitting up the stack since its getting large

Comment: I've used the SecureString SSM Parameters for my actual stack, so I don't have to keep parameters in infra stack. Then I get parameters values via CLI in buildspec.yml commands while CodeBuild creating docker images. I've also declared only one paramater "StackNamePrefix" and then generate the actual parameters names like this: `SOME_KEY=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name /$STACK_PREFIX/common/some-key --with-decryption --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)`

Comment: @SergeyCherepanov so the `SOME_KEY=...` part is in CodeBuild? How do I pass it off to the CloudFormation (`CHANGE_SET_REPLACE` and `CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE`) part of the Pipeline?

Comment: Are you deploying new version of the CFN stack in CodeDeploy or CodeBuild? In my example those command was a part of `buildspec.yml` file that is run while CodeBuild step

Comment: My understanding of what you're doing is this: you define a CodePipeline pipeline in Cloudformation, which itself deploys your infrastructure using the CloudFormation action in CodePipeline. But you have some parameters in your infrastructure templates which need to be filled in by CodePipeline. To do that you need to define them in the corresponding "CD template" which contains your CodePipeline pipeline, right? What kind of parameters are you passing here? In my experience it's usually just static values like "Stage" (eg., "beta", "prod"). Could you give an example of what you're passing in?